# C++ - Initializing SOCKADDR_IN

Tags: c++, initialization, winsock

I am working through some Static Analysis defects and one that is causing me an issue is this one.

```
SOCKADDR_IN m_stLclAddr;
```

[SOCKADDR_IN is a member of the WinSock API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The defect is saying that I have not initialized the following:

- m_stLclAddr.sin_port
- m_stLclAddr.sin_zero
- m_stLclAddr.sin_addr
- m_stLclAddr.sin_family

I am not very familiar familiar with the WinSock API but I have done a bit of research and I just want to know if the following line of code would initialize m_stLclAddr with default values?:

```
m_stLclAddr = { 0 };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`m_stLclAddr = {0}` will set everything to zero the first time (not necessarily default values or what you actually want to do).  `memset(&m_stLclAddr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));` will set everything in m_stLclAddr to zero for not only initialization, but successive calls as well.

I would think you would want to do something like this:

```
local_sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
local_sin.sin_port = htons (PORTNUM);
local_sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
```

as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa454002.aspx

Comment: m_stLclAddr = {0} sets the first char to zero and then the rest will be zeros by auto, m_stLclAddr = {} will set all to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `{0}` will intialize `m_stLclAddr` to all zero's